# Angular2 RC5 router can't find module (lazy load)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a pretty simple Angular2 RC5 test project which attempts to use routing to lazy load modules. I can't see what's wrong with the project.

**Folders**

```
app
  |-about (contains about.module.ts and about.component.ts)
  |-home (contains home.module.ts, home.component.ts)
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: './app/home/home.module' },
    { path: 'about', loadChildren: './app/about/about.module' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent }    from './home.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HomeComponent],
    exports: [HomeComponent]
})

export default class HomeModule { }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component }        from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: `<h2>Home...</h2>`
})

export class HomeComponent { }
```

I know the redirect to "home" is working, at startup I can see that home.module.js and home.component.js files are downloaded, but then it throws a console error message `Cannot find 'HomeModule' in './app/home/home.module'` (and in the network traffic tab I can confirm that both of the js files are correct, spelling is correct, etc.)

Comment: I suppose I should also mention I'm using router 3.0.0-rc.1, which is the latest as of Angular2 RC5, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace:

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './app/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
```

Into this line:

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './app/home/home.module' },
```

If you already add **export default** in your module file, you do not have to specify name in path.

Of course, if you forgot about "default", the only way to select proper module is to add #name attribute - this is the *second way*. You could use one of them, **not both**.

And also in your **HomeModule**, add:

```
imports: [ 
    RouterModule.forChil‌​d([ 
       { path: '', component: HomeComponent } 
    ]) 
],
```

Because all modules could have few components (not only one) so it is necessary to show angular a path to your main component.

Comment: Thanks, but if I remove either **default** (and only "default", keeping `export class HomeModule`) _or_ if I remove the #name tag, it hangs for awhile then blows the stack. If I remove **export default** (leaving only `class HomeModule` and retain the #name tag, I get the same `Cannot find module` error.

Comment: No no, you can't remove export word. Try to remove #HomeModule and keep stay "default". So - { path: 'home', loadChildren: './app/home/home.module' } and export default class HomeModule. Do you have any error message now?

Comment: Sure, editing now. Stack error: http://imgur.com/q2BM7r9

(Sorry, previous reply was wrong -- if I only remove **default** _or_ if I only remove the #name tag in the route, it blows the stack.)

Comment: In your HomeModule, add:

imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
        ])
    ],

Comment: Awesome. That worked... but why, I thought the declarations was enough...?

Comment: Because you only tell angular which module should be loaded. All modules could have few components (not only one) so it is necessary to show angular a path to your main component :)

Comment: It was `forRoot` and `forChild` that was throwing me -- I didn't realize until now they're related to service injection rather than routing specifically.